# Unity3D-How do I make a balance board?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I'm making a test game, and I want to set a plane that tilts when the rolling ball I control with direction keys moves in that direction, kind of like a see-saw. Does anyone have any ideas for how to go about that?

Here's what I'm trying with code. I attatched it to the plane.

```
public class Balance : MonoBehaviour {

    public float weight = 20f;
    Rigidbody rb;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            rb.AddForce(-transform.forward * weight, ForceMode.Acceleration);
            rb.useGravity = true;
        }
    }
}
```

New Ball Settings
[image: New Ball Settings]

[Floor Collider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXOGi.png)

Comment: Why are you setting useGravity on each trigger? That should be done in the Start function once. Also, post a screenshot that shows what's going on. Note that you can increase the mass of the rolling ball's Rigidbody

Comment: Ok. I posted the picture in the link Balance Board settings

Comment: Can you create a gif of how it is behaving and post that?

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Also, this is **not a forum**, do not treat it like one.

Answer (score 4):

What you would need to do is put the plane on a hinge in the center then enable gravity for the plain but not for the object that is the other side of the hinge.

Here is the documentation for the [hinge joint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-HingeJoint.html), and here is a video tutorial on [physics joints](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/physics-joints?playlist=17120) that covers hinges.

Comment: ok. How would I trigger the ball to add weight to a specific side of the plane?

Comment: @user8048595 You don't. By adding force to the ball and rolling on the plane, the physics should handle that. Please give this a try before making further comments. If you are still lost, you can edit your question without what you have done and the issue it.

Comment: I tried, but it's either doing nothing or sinks onto its side. I set the axis and anchor to the center. I just added the code Balance to my question.

Comment: You should not need your Balance script at all, it can be all done with the physics system with nothing special being done on via scripts.

Comment: Ok, I got rid of my script. and set the hinge in the center of the plane. The plan doesn't flip around, but it just doesn't do anything. Do I need to add some kind of weight in the ball script? Do I need to connect the center with an object?

Comment: if I dont check isKinematic on stage5, the ball will fall through it

Comment: If you are falling though the stage you are likely missing a collider for the floor or ball or both. Does your floor have a mesh collider?

Comment: My floor has a mesh collider and my ball has a sphere collider. Its just the ball that falls through the floor. I'm sure it has to do with the floor's rigidbody.

Comment: Its just the ball that falls through the floor. I'm think it has to do with the floor's rigidbody. The ball moves fine on the other floors.

Comment: I posted the ball and floor settings, I cant post two at once

Comment: You need to include a 3rd picture of the collider for the floor. Also, feel free to delete old comments, i have deleted mine.

Comment: Ok, Just added it